# Javascript SetInterval call back unexpected halt

Tags: javascript

I don't know why a function with setInterval stops when the preceding function (which is an animation) stops.

My code goes like this:
waitUntil is the function which stops unexpectedly
and the move is the animation function

```
move(0.1, element, yEnd, "top", 1)
waitUntil()

function waitUntil() {
    id = setInterval(continuouslyCheckVariation, 10)
    function continuouslyCheckVariation() {
        trial++// trial is a global variable
        console.log(trial)
    }
}

function move(inc, element, endPosition, direction, t) {
    let startPositionPx = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(direction));
    let startPosition = fomPixelToPercentage(startPositionPx, direction)
    console.log(endPosition)
    id = setInterval(moove, t)
    var c = startPosition
    function moove() {
        //  element.innerHTML = c + ",       " + startPosition
        if (direction == "top") {
            if (startPosition > endPosition) {
                if (c > endPosition) {
                    c = c - inc
                    element.style.top = c + "%"

                } else clearInterval(id)
            } else {
                if (c < endPosition) {
                    c = c + inc
                    element.style.top = c + "%"

                } else clearInterval(id)
            }
        } else {
            if (startPosition > endPosition) {
                if (c > endPosition) {
                    c = c - inc
                    element.style.left = c + "%"
                } else clearInterval(id)
            } else {
                if (c < endPosition) {
                    c = c + inc
                    element.style.left = c + "%"
                } else clearInterval(id)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you consider the function to stop as expected, and when not? There is `clearInteral(id)` at several places, which will indeed stop the interval from calling the callback again.

Comment: Note however that you use `id` at two places for identifying a different interval timer. You don't declare `id` with `var` or `let`, so that is an implicit global variable. You should make sure to declare your variables properly.

Comment: But there is no clearInterval in waitUntil function and yet it stops when move function stops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have only one `id` variable, and since you first call `move`, the first value it gets is within `move`

```
id = setInterval(moove, t)
```

Then, in your global script, you call `waitUntil`, and there you *overwrite* the value of `id`:

```
id = setInterval(continuouslyCheckVariation, 10)
```

Then the timer for calling `moove` expires, and `moove` is called. It can execute the following:

```
clearInterval(id)
```

...but this `id` is no longer the identifier of the interval that was set in `move`, but the one that was set in `waitUntil`, so it clears the *wrong* interval.

You should always declare your variables, so to limit their scope, to avoid such unintended overwriting.

For instance, within `move`, use `var` as follows:

```
var id = setInterval(moove, t)
```

... and now this `id` is no longer the same variable as the other, global `id`.